# How to create skin object in dnn 7?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Please tell me the steps in detail to create a skin object as I am unable to access the asp controls(Textbox etc) in the code behind of skin object, is there any setting to be done in .dnn file or web config etc.

> I am creating a custom login skin object, whenever the login button click event occurs the **myTextbox.Text in code behind comes to be null.** I have searched the video tutorials but coudn't find anything fruitful, please revert asap.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your namespaces are correct? What is your SkinObject inheriting from?

Is your DLL in the /bin folder of the website?

Comment: my namespaces are correct. My skin object is inheriting from skinobjectbase class and my dll is also in the bin folder of the website. Is it necessary that we have run extension wizard for skin object as we do for modules?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to have the skinobject registered with DNN.

Comment: I am facing another problem, i have to configure the code with tfs so that my co-developers can also work at same time,How to achieve this??.. Secondly i created a module with one control(web user control), it worked fine.. again i added another control in the same module but when i drag the module only the previous control is visible... Is it that we have to create different modules for different controls and if not then how can i get my second control on another page??

Comment: You really should spend some time with the Module Development Wiki http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Module-Development

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..now I am creating a custom Login Skin Object and my namespaces are correct But still my Asp Control values e.g. textBox1.text are coming Null in code behind.
I have followed the procedure step by step for creaing Skin Objects but still facing this prob. :(
Please tell me the Correct Steps to create a Skin Object asap.